# Using an IntentService to update CardView item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-cardview

I started implementing material design in my android application and I used a card View for displaying data in the main activity. The data I want to display in the main activity of my application is to be measured using a Service and I am wondering if there is any way to receive broadcasts from the service to update my card view items periodically. To insert data into the card view, I use a class called "Landscape" to insert the data and into the card view. At this stage of the work, the application does not measure the data yet. The source code of the Java class is given below;

**Landscape.java**

```
package com.anticdroid.egbenchong.antic_qos_monitor.activities.model;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Landscape {

private String pName;
private String pDescription;
private String pValue;
private String unit;

public void setpName(String pName){

    this.pName = pName;
}

public void setpDescription(String pDescription)
{
    this.pDescription = pDescription;
}

public void setpValue(String pValue){

    this.pValue = pValue;
}

public void setUnit(String unit){

    this.unit = unit;
}

public String getpName(){

    return pName;
}

public String getpDescription(){

    return pDescription;
}

public String getpValue(){

    return pValue;
}

public String getUnit(){

    return unit;
}

public static ArrayList<Landscape> getData(){

    ArrayList<Landscape> dataList = new ArrayList<>();


    //operator
    String[] operator = getOperator();

    Landscape landscape = new Landscape();
    landscape.setpName(operator[0]);
    landscape.setpDescription(operator[1]);
    landscape.setpValue(operator[2]);
    landscape.setUnit(operator[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape);

    String[] lac = getLac();

    Landscape landscape1 = new Landscape();
    landscape1.setpName(lac[0]);
    landscape1.setpDescription(lac[1]);
    landscape1.setpValue(lac[2]);
    landscape1.setUnit(lac[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape1);

    String[] cellid = getCellId();

    Landscape landscape2 = new Landscape();
    landscape2.setpName(cellid[0]);
    landscape2.setpDescription(cellid[1]);
    landscape2.setpValue(cellid[2]);
    landscape2.setUnit(cellid[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape2);

    String[] mnc = getMNC();

    Landscape landscape3 = new Landscape();
    landscape3.setpName(mnc[0]);
    landscape3.setpDescription(mnc[1]);
    landscape3.setpValue(mnc[2]);
    landscape3.setUnit(mnc[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape3);

    String[] rssi = getRssi();

    Landscape landscape4 = new Landscape();
    landscape4.setpName(rssi[0]);
    landscape4.setpDescription(rssi[1]);
    landscape4.setpValue(rssi[2]);
    landscape4.setUnit(rssi[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape4);

    String[] rxqual = getRxQual();

    Landscape landscape5 = new Landscape();
    landscape5.setpName(rxqual[0]);
    landscape5.setpDescription(rxqual[1]);
    landscape5.setpValue(rxqual[2]);
    landscape5.setUnit(rxqual[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape5);

    String[] netType = getNetType();

    Landscape landscape6 = new Landscape();
    landscape6.setpName(netType[0]);
    landscape6.setpDescription(netType[1]);
    landscape6.setpValue(netType[2]);
    landscape6.setUnit(netType[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape6);

    String[] upload = getUpload();

    Landscape landscape7 = new Landscape();
    landscape7.setpName(upload[0]);
    landscape7.setpDescription(upload[1]);
    landscape7.setpValue(upload[2]);
    landscape7.setUnit(upload[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape7);

    String[] download = getDownload();

    Landscape landscape8 = new Landscape();
    landscape8.setpName(download[0]);
    landscape8.setpDescription(download[1]);
    landscape8.setpValue(download[2]);
    landscape8.setUnit(download[3]);

    dataList.add(landscape8);


    return dataList;
}

private static String[] getNetType() {

    String[] net = {"NetType", "Network Type", "GPRS", ""};
    return net;
}

private static String[] getDownload() {

    String[] download = {"Download", "Download Speed", "75", "kbps"};
    return download;
}

private static String[] getUpload() {

    String[] upload = {"Upload", "Upload Speed", "42", "kbps"};
    return upload;
}

private static String[] getRxQual() {

    String[] rxqual = {"RxQual", "Received SIgnal Quality", "89", "%"};
    return rxqual;
}

private static String[] getRssi() {

    String[] rssi = {"RxLev","Received Signal Level", "-81", "dBm" };
    return rssi;
}

private static String[] getMNC() {

    String[] mnc = {"MNC", "Mobile Network Code", "624", ""};

    return mnc;
}

private static String[] getCellId() {

    String[] cellid = {"CID", "Cell Identity", "51",""};
    return cellid;
}

private static String[] getLac() {

    String[] lac = {"LAC", "Location Area Code", "2475241", ""};
    return lac;
}

public static String[] getOperator(){

    String[] operator = {"Mobile Operator", "Voice and Data Service provider", "MTN", ""};

    return operator;
}

}
```

As you can see from the previous methods such as `getOperator()`, I want to be able to modify these values using data received from an IntentService. 
I had recently updated data from a service in the main activity of my application since it was a direct broadcast. I don't know if it will apply in this case. Please I need help?

Comment: Nothing differs. You could send broadcast from IntenService

Comment: you mean send the broadcast updates to the Landscape class? will it be automatically displayed in the UI when the values change?

Comment: Register your BroadcastReceiver in activity(or fragment) then handle each broadcast from service, and update your UI via your handled data.

Comment: it works fine. I had to use the methods for adding and removing an item from the cardview